# Or criteria on PivotTable via Slicer?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, slicers

I have a mind-bender here. There is a PivotTable with two columns representing Doctors. So the first column heading is **Doctor_1** and next to it is **Doctor_2**.

Each line in the pivot table represents an interaction between two doctors. Like, one consults the other. So any Doctor can be Doctor_1 or Doctor_2.

I've been figure out a way to have a Slicer emulate an "Or" condition on the two columns such that if "Dr. Smith" exists in either column, that line is retained while others are filtered.

Answer (score 1):

To get a slicer to work this way you would have to add a new column - let's call it "Doctor Who" - and then list each item in the raw data twice...the first time with the name from Doctor_1 in the "Doctor Who" column, and the second time with Doctor_2 in the "Doctor Who" column.

One way you could do this is by unpivoting the data, so that Doctor_1 and Doctor_2 get consolidated into a new field called "Doctor". If you have a version of Excel with the PowerQuery functionality (aka "Get and Transform") you can use that. Otherwise you could use the code I wrote previously at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/ to do this. Or give Google a spin for "UnPivot" and "Excel"

Comment: Thank you for your reply! (And the only one, to boot.) I just had a thought. Using Power Query, I could add an Index, then produce two tables. The original data, and a second table (with some M futzing) that has the original index duplicated for each of the two Doctors per line. Then using PowerPivot, connect the two tables with an inner join. Then, have the Slicer filter the second dataset. Just thinking out loud here. And hey, thanks for that link. SNB's code always amazes and your additions make the original code so much more useful. Yeah, I copied that!